# Yii2 select2 widget return saved results

Tags: jquery-select2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

How can I display saved database rows on kartik Select2 widget? I set the multiple option to `true` and it works fine. I saved 3 records in database table and now I am trying to display them on model update. Tried to put them in the `value` property of the widget but nothing happens. This is what I declared :

```
 <?=
                        Select2::widget([
                            'name' => 'categories',
                            'data' => Attribute::getAllCategoriesSelect2(),
                            'options' => [
                                'multiple' => true,
                                'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select categories'),
                                'allowClear' => true
                            ],
                        ])
                    ?>
```

What i've tried is to put my records like this : `'value' => $data`, where `$data` is:

```
$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
                            ->select(['page.id', 'pageLang.title'])
                            ->from('page')
                            ->leftJoin('pageLang', 'page.id=pageLang.page_id')
                            ->rightJoin('attribute_category', 'page.id=attribute_category.category_id')
                            ->where('pageLang.language=:lang', [':lang' => Yii::$app->language])
                            ->andWhere('page.is_cat=1')
                            ->all();
```

I didn't find any explanation about this in the kartik documentation. Can you guys give me an advice? Thank you!

Comment: the multiple values that you select on the first hand to save the new record how are you saving them are you using a separate table to save the selected values or save them as a comma separated value inside a single field ?

Comment: Separete table. Each value is a row.